# MySQL How to SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS from two table along with the name of description

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax, exists, not-exists

I have two table and need to select user who not exist in log_k_b, along with the name of description of kb.

Table: user

| id | deleted | user_name | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | admin | admin | admin |
| 5ee | 0 | agent01 | agent1 | agent |
| 3fe | 0 | agent02 | agent2 | agent |
| 4ff | 0 | agent03 | agent3 | agent |

Table: log_k_b

| id | k_b_id | deleted | description | created_by_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5fe18ef2425a093ea | 0 | Program Provider | 5ee | 2023-03-08 03:25:16 |
| 2 | 5fe18ef2425a093ea | 0 | Program Provider | 5ee | 2023-03-08 03:33:57 |

And this is result of query

| userId | userName | k_b_id | description | created_by_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 3fe | agent02 | [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] |
| 4ff | agent03 | [NULL] | [NULL] | [NULL] |

But The result should looks like this

| userId | userName | k_b_id | description | created_by_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | 5fe18ef2425a093ea | Program Provider | 5ee |
| 3fe | agent02 | 5fe18ef2425a093ea | Program Provider | 5ee |
| 4ff | agent03 | 5fe18ef2425a093ea | Program Provider | 5ee |

I am trying to query the result from User who did not create KB along with KB Description

My query is had structure like this (this sample not show anything):

```
select distinct u.id as userId, u.user_name as userName, lkb.name as kbId, lkb.description as kbName
from user u
left join log_k_b lkb on u.id = lkb.created_by_id
where not exists (select u2.id as user_id, lkb2.created_by_id as created_by_id, lkb2.description as kb_name, max(lkb2.created_at) as latest_date
                  from user u2 left join log_k_b lkb2 on u2.id = lkb2.created_by_id
                  where u2.id = lkb2.created_by_id )
```

Comment: Can you show us what's you have tried so far? especially the relataed sql

Comment: My query is had structure like this (this sample not show anything): 

select distinct
   u.id as userId,
   u.user_name as userName,
   lkb.name  as kbId,
   lkb.description as kbName
from user u
left join log_k_b lkb on u.id = lkb.created_by_id 
where not exists (
   select
      u2.id as user_id,
      lkb2.created_by_id as created_by_id,
      lkb2.description as kb_name,
      max(lkb2.created_at) as latest_date
   from user u2
   left join log_k_b lkb2 on u2.id = lkb2.created_by_id
   where u2.id = lkb2.created_by_id
)

Comment: Does this mean there can only be one KB creator in table `log_k_b` at a time? Because if there were multiple, how could we match which Non_KB_creator to which KB_creator ?

Comment: The NOT EXISTS subquery needs to be _correlated_.

Comment: table log_k_b is store log who create or edit KB, but i want to know user who did not create/edit KB

Comment: @jarlh do you have any sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your question as: for each KB, bring the list of users that did not participated it.

Here is one way to do it:

```
select u.id, u.user_name, k.k_b_id, k.description
from user u
cross join (select distinct k_b_id, description from log_k_b) k
where not exists (
    select 1 from log_k_b k1 where k1.created_by_id = u.id and k1.k_b_id = k.k_b_id
)
```

The idea is to generate a cartesian join of the users and the KBs; then, we use `not exists` to filter out tuples that already exist in the log table. This assumes that a given KB always has the same description.

Normally, you would have a separate table to store the KBs, that you would use instead of the `select distinct` subquery.

Comment: `k.description from log_k_b) k`, should be `description from log_k_b) k`